# Limitar o valor de TextBox tendo em conta a soma dos seus valores

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu tenho a seguinte tabela em que estão incluidos 3 textbox's correspondentes a percentagens, o que prentendo é que quando o utilizador insere os valores nas 2 primeiras TextBox's , o 3º valor apareça com o valor que sobra da subtração de 100 com a soma das outras duas textBox's. Por exemplo , se for escrito na 1º textb's o valor de 50 , e na 2º o valor de 25, terá de aparecer no 3º automaticamente  o valor de 25. Pode ser em Javascript ou Jquery.

```
<table id="myTable6">
  <thead>
      <tr>
           <th><label>Peso das Nota</label></th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
        <form><td><label>Testes: </label><input type="text" name="nome" id="mySelect11"> 
                  <label>Exame:  </label><input type="text" name="nome" id="mySelect12">
                  <label>Trabalhos:</label>  <input type="text" name="nome" id="mySelect13"></td>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#mySelect12").on("blur",function(){
  var valor1 = parseFloat($("#mySelect11").val());
  var calc = 100 - (parseFloat($(this).val()) + valor1);
  $("#mySelect13").val(calc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable6">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <label>Peso das Nota</label>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <form>
      <td>
        <label>Testes:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="mySelect11">
        <br><br>
        <label>Exame:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="mySelect12">
        <br><br>
        <label>Trabalhos:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="mySelect13">
      </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```